# Unable to pass XML in xsl script

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, client-side

Below is the XML and XSL and i want to pass the complete xml node to xsl script to do some operations on that node and I do not want to use XPATH and want to operate using selectsinglenode in msxslscript.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="doc.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<books>
<book>
<name>Revolution</name>
<qty value="4">1</qty>
</book>
<book>
<name>Life of a pie</name>
<qty value="4">5</qty>
</book>
</books>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:user="com.nitish">
<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user" >
function getNode(node){

return node.selectSingleNode("books/book/qty/@value");

}
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="/">


<html>
<body>
<h2>Book Details</h2>
<table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" border="1px" cellspacing="20px">
<xsl:variable name="rootNode" select="books"/>
<xsl:for-each select="//book">
<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="user:getNode($rootNode)"/>
</td></tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't see any use of `selectSingleNode` in your sample so if `selectSingleNode` is the problem you face then show a sample with that, explaining in detail the result you expect and how the one you get differs. Or at least explain for the samples posted what is the problem, i.e. which result you expect and how the result you get differs. Do you get any error? Are you using IE? Otherwise the whole approach with msxsl:script is not supported at all.

Comment: I want to fetch the value of qty attribute using selectSingleNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to understand why you insist on using a proprietary feature like extension script to simply select nodes and output their values as that is what XSLT and XPath are for but if you need an example then with IE the following works for me:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2014110601.xsl"?>
<books>
<book>
<name>Revolution</name>
<qty value="4">1</qty>
</book>
<book>
<name>Life of a pie</name>
<qty value="4">5</qty>
</book>
</books>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:user="http://example/com/user"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl user">

<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user">
function getNode(nodeSelection) {
  return nodeSelection.item(0).selectSingleNode("book/qty/@value");
}
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="rootElement" select="books"/>
  <html>
    <body>
      <h2>Book Details</h2>
      <div>
        <h3>XPath</h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rootElement/book/qty/@value"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Script</h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="user:getNode($rootElement)"/>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014110601.xml. Outputs with IE

```
Book Details


XPath
4

Script
4
```